# Mapping many to one table relation to view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to map a many to one relationship. I feel I'm close but not quite there.

I have this sensor table:

```
SensorId
FK_LocationId
Name
etc...
```

Which holds many data records in the `Data` Table.

```
DataId
FK_SensorId
Time
Value
```

And I am trying to create a Model for this.

```
public class DataSensor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DataNodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool active;
    public bool alarm;
}

public class GatheredData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DataSensorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public float value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DataSensorId")]
    public virtual DataSensor datasensor { get; set; }
}
```

It should actually be the other way around, at least in my mind. Where the sensor would hold a `List<Data>` but there is no FK to link that in Sensor. A `Data` record is just mapped to a sensor by the FK of that sensor.

The problem I'm facing here is that I would have this line in my view now:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataVisualization.Models.Data>
```

And instead of looping over my sensors to display the information and then show the data (eventually a chart). I have to loop all the data, somehow organize it how I want and then display it. So I would still need:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataVisualization.Models.DataSensor>
```

But this does not give me access to the data since that is in `Data` and `DataSensor` does not expose any of that afaik. So I thought about somekind of class that maps them together:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public DataSensor dataSensor { get; set; }
    public List<GatheredData> gatheredData { get; set; }
}
```

And my view would require:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataVisualization.Models.DataViewModel>
```

This seemed an elegant way but I was not able to make it work. Probably since this would require `public DbSet<DataViewModel> dataViewModel { get; set; }` in the `DbContext` and that would produce a awkward table in my database.

So any help on how to create the Model, work with it in the Controller and displaying it in the View would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

What about this Model so I have access to the data connected to this?

```
public class DataSensor
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DataNodeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool active;
    public bool alarm;

    public virtual ICollection<DataSensor> Data { get; set; }
}
```

However, this creates a column `DataSensor_Id` in the database table. This obviously is undesirable since then it would be a one to one.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to leave my other answer below because it still provides valuable information.

This is how you can accomplish just pulling the data from the database for display. You are using the database first approach. I would recommend creating a new project to test this and get accustomed to what is taking place. Now you are going to want to go to tools in the ribbon and select connect to database. Enter the relevant information to connect to the database. Now create new project, if you haven't already. For the purpose of learning create an Asp.Net5 web application with no authentication. Now, go to your NuGet Package Manager Console. Run " Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer -Pre ". Once that is completed Run " Install-Package EntityFramework.Commands –Pre " and " Install-Package EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer.Design –Pre ". Once those are installed go to your Project.Json file and in the commands section add "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands" . Now, go to command prompt and cd to your projects directory. The easiest way I have found to do this is to right click your project and open folder in file explorer. Once you do that, go up one level so all you see is one folder. If you see all of the contents of your project then that is NOT the right place. Shift+RightClick on the folder and you should see the option to Open Command Window Here. Click that and once Command Prompt has opened in your project directory. Run

> dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1

or I have found that not to work in some cases. If that doesn't work then Run

> dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final

If neither of these work you need to install 1.0.0-rc1. Once one of those work, Run

> dnx ef dbcontext scaffold
> "Server=EnterYourConnectionStringHere;Database=YourDataBaseNameHere;Trusted_Connection=True;"
> EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer --outputDir Models

Once that is complete you should have your models that were created from the database in the Models Directory. Go to your newly created Context Class in the Models Directory. Once in there you will see an override void OnConfiguring method. Delete that. Open your Startup.cs and put these using statements at the top.

> using YourProject.Models;
>
> using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

Now in your ConfigureServices Method in Startup.cs add

```
  var connection =@"Server=YourConnectionString;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;";
 
             services.AddEntityFramework()
                 .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<YourContextName>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Then the rest is just creating controllers and views for your newly registered context.

> Old Answer Below

Try using the fluent API to specify the relationship. Like this: (Hint: this is in your ApplicationDbContext.)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            
            builder.Entity<DataSensor>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Data)
                .WithOne();
        }
        public DbSet<DataSensor> DataSensor { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GatheredData> GatheredData { get; set; }
```

And your classes like this:

```
public class DataSensor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DataNodeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool active;
        public bool alarm;
        public virtual ICollection<DataSensor> Data { get; set; }

    }

    public class GatheredData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DataSensorId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public float value { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DataSensorId")]
        public virtual DataSensor datasensor { get; set; }

    }
```

You can also do this by convention like this

```
public class DataSensor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DataNodeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool active;
        public bool alarm;
        public virtual ICollection<DataSensor> Data { get; set; }

    }

    public class GatheredData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DataSensorId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public float value { get; set; }

        
        public virtual DataSensor datasensor { get; set; }

    }
```

or by data annotations like this

```
public class DataSensor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DataNodeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool active;
        public bool alarm;
        public virtual ICollection<DataSensor> Data { get; set; }

    }

    public class GatheredData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DataSensorId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public float value { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DataSensorId")]
        public virtual DataSensor datasensor { get; set; }

    }
```

If you do this by convention and it doesn't work, data annotations could help map them. If all else fails then the fluent API will override everything and map the relationship.

Now, for how to display this data. If you are just trying to display the data and not edit it then I think creating a partial view will be your best bet. In your shared folder create a blank view. Add your model to the new view.

```
@model IEnumerable<DataVisualization.Models.GatheredData>
```

Then do a foreach loop to iterate through that data.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)</p>

<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)</p>


<p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)</p>


}
```

Then back in your main View for the Datasensor put the following where you want the data.

```
@Html.Partial("StringNameOfThePartialView", Model.Data)
```

The first overload is the name of the partial view, and the second is the model data to be passed to that view.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think there is need for a API. I simply want to create a very common relation. Like a user can do many transactions and these transactions are mapped to the user in the database.

Comment: If you already have a database that you are pulling from, I think you might be going at this the wrong way. If all you are trying to do is pull from the database and display the values, there is a much easier way to do this. Let me know if this is what you are trying to do and I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, all I want is pulling all my sensors from a location and get all the data belonging to that sensor. The data and all sensor info/details are stored in the DB.

Comment: Hope the new content on the answer helps you. I left the old answer below, but you don't have to worry about that.